# Copy to clipboard solution (IOS compatible)

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have any advice on creating a copy to clipboard function that works on IOS too?
The only solution i've found are flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way to copy to the OS clipboard using JavaScript.  That means that there's not really a way to copy to the clipboard on iDevices from a web browser.

Comment: IOS unfortunately does not support Flash. :/